# C# Same Enum Name with Multiple Values

Tags: c#, enums

How to add same `Enum` name for different values like this? Any possible implementation for this?

```
public enum Location
{
   A = 1,
   A = 2,
   A = 3,
   B = 4,
   B = 5  
}
```

**Update:**

I have a db table and from that i need to create `Enum` for `Id` from that table. I need to assign same names for some `Id`'s. So that i need this kind of implementation. By passing the `Id` as value to get the `Enum` name.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Unique *names*, the values can be duplicates.

Comment: Need to map Db primary key `Id` with same name for some `Id`'s and so need have `enum`

Comment: If we knew more about what problem you were trying to solve with this approach, we could guide you in the right direction.

Comment: How can your PK in your DB have duplicates?

Comment: Isn't the "same name for multiple id's" more of a property thing on the entity object for the rows in your table, instead of an enum?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I updated my actual requirement in my question. So please check

Comment: Regardless of what you want, it is not possible to have an enum with multiple keys with the same name but with different values. You're going to have to find a different solution. Can you live with having underscores? Like `A`, `A_`, and `A__` ? Or, can't you just use the name as a `string` instead?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen,Thanks, I need to display the unique name in view for certain `Ids`. For eg. Id `1` and `2`, i need to display as `A`.

Comment: `var val = Location.A;` - what do you expect the compiler to do with that? (Unless you have a quantum computer)

Comment: You say "unique name", but obviously it is not unique. Just add a calculated property on the entity object (or whatever), and return a string.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, I just need the reverse case `Enum.GetName(typeof(Location), dbValue);`

Comment: Then you don't need an enum - you need a `Dictionary<int,string>`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Yes i agree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The enum names has to be unique.

Their *values*, however, can be duplicates, so you can do the reverse thing:

```
A = 1,
B = 2,
C = 2,
D = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Lasse Said it is not possible. but for your job you can create your own `custom type` so.

```
public class customtype
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public List<int> values { get; set; } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Regard of this we can just use `Dictionary` object itself. But i just need to know if that happens with enum.

Comment: You **can't use** an enum!

Comment: @SSS yea you can use. But I thought you might need to do some more manipulation. Unfortunately you can't do it with `Enums`!

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible; the explanation is quite simple: just imagine the code:

```
  int loc = (int) (Location.A);
```

What should the loc be? 1, 2 or 3? However, you can assign aliases: many 
names for one value:

```
  public enum Location
  {
   A = 1,
   B = 1,
   C = 1,
   D = 2,
   E = 2,
   F = 3 
  }
```

In case you convert from int back to enum

```
   Location loc = (Location) 2; // <- Location.D
```

there'll be the first enum value with corresponding int value 
(Location.D in the case)

Comment: +1, Thanks for the detailed explanation. Is there any other simple possible implementation for my case?

Answer (score 0):

If the only aspect of an `enum` that you're using is the `Enum.GetName` function, to translate an `int` into a `string`, then you don't need an `enum` - you just need a properly initialised `Dictionary<int,string>`, e.g.

```
public static Dictionary<int,string> Location = new Dictionary<int,string>
{
  {1,"A"},
  {2,"A"},
  {3,"A"},
  {4,"B"},
  {5,"B"}
}
```

And you can now just access `Location[Id]` rather than using `GetName`.